# SignalR - notification order

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I know this issue was raised many times, but I couldn't find a real answer, my clients are registered to groups and the server sends notifications on changes, do I need to use sequences so the client will re-order it? or can i trust on order delivery for each client?

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

SignalR doesn't guarantee message delivery but the message order should normally be preserved